# Reduce empty space in ggplot2 donut chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, margin

I tried hard, but could not find an answer on SO that helped in my case...

With the following code I create a donut chart in R using the `ggplot2`-package:

```
library(ggplot2)

test_data <- data.frame(Test = 1:4, Freq = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))

ggplot(test_data, aes(x = 2, y = Freq, fill = Test)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
  theme_void() +
  xlim(c(-1, 2.5)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = -1, y = 0, label = "Test", size = 60/.pt) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.background = element_rect(color="red", linewidth = 2))
```

The resulting chart has much of empty white space around the actual plot. How can I reduce or crop this margin within R?

[image: Plot with empty space]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use `plot.margin` within `theme` to adjust as needed.

```
library(ggplot2)

test_data <- data.frame(Test = 1:4, Freq = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))

ggplot(test_data, aes(x = 2, y = Freq, fill = Test)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) +
  theme_void() +
  xlim(c(-1, 2.5)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = -1, y = 0, label = "Test", size = 60/.pt) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.background = element_rect(color = "red", linewidth = 2),
        plot.margin = margin(-1, -1, -1, -1, "cm")) # Try to adjust as needed
```

Comment: My goodness - trying almost anything for hours - and the answer is NEGATIVE NUMBERS in the margin? I never heard about using negative numbers in `margin`. Thanks for pointing me at this @geek45!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `expand` argument of `scale_x_continuous` will allow the plot to fill the space without having to change the margin every time you rescale the plot:

```r
ggplot(test_data, aes(x = 2, y = Freq, fill = Test)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, -0.6), limits = c(-1, 2.5)) +
  theme_void() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = -1, y = 0, label = "Test", size = 60/.pt) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.background = element_rect(color="red", linewidth = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Good alternative to the solution of @geek45. But the annotation has moved down. Why that?